# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am very new to Laravel and PHP, just trying to export to PDF using dompdf all detail city in my view file like this:

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

```
@foreach($city as $detail)
<h1>Nama Kota : {{$detail->city_name}}</h1><br>
<h1>Size : {{$detail->size}}</h1><br>
<h1>Population : {{$detail>population}}</h1> 
@endforeach
```

and here my controller

```
 public function export($id)
{
    $city=City::find($id);

    return $this->exportPdf($city);
}

public function exportPdf($city)
{
    $data['city'] = $city;
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('cities.PrintView',$data);
    return $pdf->download('capital.pdf');
}
```

and i got error Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you don't pass the variable in your view?

Comment: @aldrin27 i pass $city variable

Answer (score 1):

aha!! i know my faults... ^^
it should be:

```
  public function exportPdf($city)
{
    $data['city'] = $city;
    $name = DB::table('cities')
        ->select('city_name','size','population')
        ->where('cities.id', 'LIKE', '%'.$city.'%')->distinct()
        ->get();
  //  dd($name);
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('cities.PrintView',compact('name'));
    return $pdf->download('capital.pdf');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're fetching a single instance of city, the foreach statement will expect a collection.

Try `dd($city=City::find($id));` to view the output.

Use `$city=City::all();` which will return a collection and then the foreach statement should work.

Also

try

`loadView('cities.PrintView',compact('city'))`

Comment: Did `dd($city=City::find($id));` return anything?

Comment: i'm trying to dd($city); not return anything.. maybe i'm totally wrong :'(

Comment: Sounds like you have an issue getting the data not sending it to the PDF generator